# iOS5 Facebook API : Get Friends and show

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I'm developing a app that integrates with Facebook API (iOS 5). And I'm trying to get the user friends pictures to show on the initial screen.
I downloaded an example that have a class FriendPickerDelegate, and presents to user a list of his friends in a Table, and he select it.
But, I don't know how to get an array of his friends, just for presents on the screen the pictures of them.

How can I do this?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In [this example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/personalize/), you can learn how to get information about the logged user (/me). To get your friends, you should do something like that, but instead of using `[FBRequest requestForMe]`, you'd use `[FBRequest requestForMyFriends]` (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.0/class/FBRequest#requestForMyFriends).